# Simple respond_with in rails that avoids 204 from PUT

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to `PUT` to rails and avoid getting a `204`. I am using this pattern:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def update
    # ...
    respond_with(some_object)
  end
end
```

However, when I do a `put` to update, I get a `204` back. I realize this is completely valid etc, but I explicitly want the content back. I can override it to some extent like this:

```
def update
  respond_with(some_object) do |format|
    format.json{render json: some_object}
  end
end
```

but this seems a bit too hands-on for rails. Is there any more idiomatic way of avoiding a `204` and requesting the full content to be sent back? This is Rails 3.2.

In summary: I want maximally idiomatic rails that avoids a `204`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I made a custom responder which always returns my JSON encoded resource even on PUT/POST.

I put this file in `lib/responders/json_responder.rb`. Your `/lib` dir should be autoloaded.

```
module Responders::JsonResponder
  protected

  # simply render the resource even on POST instead of redirecting for ajax
  def api_behavior(error)
    if post?
      display resource, :status => :created
    # render resource instead of 204 no content
    elsif put?
      display resource, :status => :ok
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Now, explicitly modify the controller which requires this behavior, or place it in the application controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery

  responders :json

end
```

You should now get JSON encoded resources back on PUT.

Comment: I would add that you need the 'responders' gem to be able to use the responders method in your controller.

Answer (score 13):

As a less invasive alternative, you can pass a `json:` option to the `respond_with` method invocation inside your controller `update` action, like this:

```
def update
  # ...
  respond_with some_object, json: some_object
end
```

Granted it seems a bit unDRY having to repeat the object twice in the arguments, but it'll give you what you want, the json representation of the object in the response of a PUT request, and you don't need to use the `render json:` way, which won't give you the benefits of responders.

However, if you have a lot of controllers with this situation, then customizing the responders, as jpfuentes2 showed in the accepted anwser, is the way to go. But for a quick single case, this alternative may be easier.

Source: https://github.com/plataformatec/responders/pull/115#issuecomment-72517532

Comment: awesome, it fixed my issue at the shortest time.

Answer (score 11):

This behavior seems intentional to fall in line with the HTTP spec, and "ideally" you should be firing off an additional GET request to see the results. However, I agree in the real world I'd rather have it return the JSON.

@jpfuentes2's solution above should do the trick (it's very similar to the pull request below), but I'm hesitant to apply anything that's patching rails internals, as it could be a real pain to upgrade between major versions, especially if you don't have tests for it (and let's face it, developers often skimp on controller tests).

References

- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9862
- https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9887

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right, I'd rather make another `$.get` from `JS` than start to fight a framework.

Answer (score 9):

Just to clarify, you do not need the responders gem to do this...  You can just do:

## config/initializers/responder_with_put_content.rb

```
class ResponderWithPutContent < ActionController::Responder
  def api_behavior(*args, &block)
    if put?
      display resource, :status => :ok
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

and then either (for all updates actions to be affected):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def self.responder
    ResponderWithPutContent
  end
end
```

or in your action:

```
def update
  foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
  foo.update_attributes(params[:foo])
  respond_with foo, responder: ResponderWithPutContent
end
```

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with simply doing:

```
def update
  some_object = SomeObject.update()
  render json: some_object
end
```

Comment: You won't get proper http response codes or errors back

Comment: Like the comment above said, you don't get any feedback on whether `update` succeeded or not.

Answer (score 1):

Not a big fan of this behavior.  To get around it, I had to avoid using the `respond_with` method:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def update
    # ...
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render(json: some_object, status: 200) }
    end
  end
end
```