# In Rails, why am I getting a "204 - No Content" response for my update/PATCH/PUT, using Active Model Serializers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, put, active-model-serializers

This code is for a UserList (a user can create a User To-Do List). This particular resource does not hold the list items, but just the title of the list, and the type of list.

```
class Api::V1::UserListsController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json
    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

    def index
        if authenticate_user
            user_lists = @current_user.user_lists
            if user_lists
                respond_with user_lists, each_serializer: Api::V1::UserListSerializer
            else
                render json: { error: "Could not find user's lists."}, status: :not_found
            end 
        else
            render json: { error: "User is not signed in." }, status: :unauthorized
        end     
    end         

    def show
        if authenticate_user
            user_lists = @current_user.user_lists
            user_list = user_lists.find_by_id(params[:id])
            if user_list
                respond_with user_list, serializer: Api::V1::UserListSerializer
            else
                render json: { error: "Could not find user's list."}, status: :not_found
            end 
        else
            render json: { error: "User is not signed in." }, status: :unauthorized
        end     
    end     

    def create
        if authenticate_user
            user_list = @current_user.user_lists.new(user_list_params)
            if (user_list.save!)
                respond_with :api, :v1, @current_user, user_list, serializer: Api::V1::UserListSerializer
            else
                render json: { error: "Could not create new User List."}, status: :unprocessable_entity
            end         
        else
            render json: { error: "User is not signed in." }, status: :unauthorized
        end
    end

    def update
        if authenticate_user
            user_list = @current_user.user_lists.find_by_id(params[:id])

            if (user_list.update_attributes(user_list_update_params))
                respond_with :api, :v1, @current_user, user_list, serializer: Api::V1::UserListSerializer                                  
                                    #respond_with user_list, serializer: Api::V1::UserListSerializer
            else
                render json: { error: "Could not update User List." }, status: :unprocessable_entity
            end
        end
    end

    private

        def user_list_params
            params.require(:user_list).permit(:user_id, :type_id, :title)
        end

        def user_list_update_params
            params.require(:user_list).permit(:type_id, :title)
        end
end
```

Now the update works when I PUT/PATCH... but I get a

```
Completed 204 No Content in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 4.3ms)
```

It's been about 4+ months since I've done any rails, and back then I was only just beginning to learn it.

**1)** Does anyone know why I'm not getting anything back? I know it's something to do with my respond_with line of code in update, but I'm not sure exactly what.

2) Can someone clarify to me the difference between the SHOW respond_with and the CREATE respond_with. I recall having an issue grasping this back then, and obviously now.

SHOW

```
respond_with user_list, serializer: Api::V1::UserListSerializer
```

CREATE

```
respond_with :api, :v1, @current_user, user_list, serializer: Api::V1::UserListSerializer
```

**a)** Why does create require :api and :v1 first, but show does not?

**b)** Why does create require the @current_user, but show does not?

Appendix: Here is my Serializer for reference

```
class Api::V1::UserListSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :user_id, :type_id, :title
  has_many :items, embed: :ids
end
```

Comment: This question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953887/simple-respond-with-in-rails-that-avoids-204-from-put

Answer (score 5):

I know this is 2 years too late, but after some digging, I found the empty response with the 204 is intentional (as mentioned above). If you use `respond_with` this will always be the case. A workaround would be to use `render` instead (example below):

```
class Api::V1::ItemsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
  ...

  def update
    @item = Item.find(params[:id]
    if @item
      @item.update_attribute(item_params)
      render json: @item
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You're not supposed to get anything back other than the 204. Any intelligent client does not need to receive back the data it just sent you -- it needs only confirmation that the data was persisted.

Comment: What about dumb clients, though? We should not discriminate by intelligence :)

Comment: It seems that Rails does not send the json response when putting. - This worked for me with Netflix/fast_jsonapi

Answer (score 0):

Do not mistakenly pass  your class `Api::V1::UserListSerializer` as a key/value pair (Hash form). You will get an error including the text **class or module needed**. It should look like this:

```
serialize :some_array, Api::V1::UserListSerializer
```

Or, perhaps clearer would be:

```
serialize(:some_array, Api::V1::UserListSerializer)
```

You miss one param and you are rendering an object class with no content : `204 - No Content`
That may seem obvious, but it is common to be in the habit of passing things as a key/value pair.

One improve:

```
before_action :authenticate_user, only: [:create, :show, :update, ...]
```

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class

Answer (score -1):

```
def update
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  respond_with(:api, :v1, @item) do |format|
    if @item.update(item_params)
      format.json { render json: @item}
    else
      format.json { render json: {error: @item.errors.full_messages}}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A
[proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve
its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make
it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer
to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.